# Problem with IIS 8.5 on prod env - it dosn't return "content-type": "application/octet-stream" from controller ASP.NET WebApi 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api2, devops

Hi I have a problem returning file on  production environment. this works on development machine. 
My controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var databaseFile = _availableDatabasesService.GetDatabaseFile(fileName);
                HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                Stream stream = databaseFile.GetStream();
                result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = fileName
                };
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Error(e.Message, e);
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
        }
```

Database file name look like : "Something_1_1_1_1.env.db",
It works only on my local IIS express, I have only access to ftp account on target hosting machine.

On my local I got headers:

```
{
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "date": "Tue, 17 Sep 2019 05:56:33 GMT",
  "server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
  "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319",
  "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
  "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "x-sourcefiles": "=?UTF-8?B?QzpcTWF0cmlzTW9iaWxlXE1hdHJpc01vYmlsZVxXZWJBcGlcTWF0cmlzTW9iaWxlLldlYkFwaVxhcGlcRGF0YWJhc2VGaWxl?=",
  "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=Xxx.Reading.SQLite_1.0.0.2_dev.db",
  "content-length": "16322560",
  "expires": "-1"
}
```

but on production :

```
{
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "date": "Tue, 17 Sep 2019 05:51:15 GMT",
  "content-encoding": "gzip",
  "server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.5",
  "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319",
  "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
  "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "content-length": "252",
  "expires": "-1"
}
```

I added also this line to web.config but it not helps:

```
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".db" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      </staticContent>
```

Please help.

---

edited:

Also return from looks like :

```
{
  "Version": {
    "_Major": 1,
    "_Minor": 1,
    "_Build": -1,
    "_Revision": -1
  },
  "Content": {
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Key": "Content-Type",
        "Value": [
          "application/octet-stream"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Key": "Content-Disposition",
        "Value": [
          "attachment; filename=Xxx.Reading.SQLite_1.0.0.2_dev.db"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
  "Headers": [],
  "RequestMessage": null,
  "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

But file download process is not started.

Comment: Is the status code of both responses `200 OK`?

Comment: @M.Stramm yes it is

Comment: MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream") works fine on my local IIS. Have you tried to clean cache or try different  client? Could you post the URL you are trying to access

Comment: @JokiesDing Yes I tried different clients, I can use simple get and it also not works : http://mydomainxyz.com/api/DatabaseFile?fileName=Xxx.Reading.SQLite_1.0.0.2_dev.db

(mydomainxyz - replaced because of company policies)

Comment: @Ruuteek When you run the application inside IIS express, the application will use your login user as a application identity. Have you tried to change IIS application pool identity to the same user? Besides, have you installed IIS asp.net module?

Comment: @JokiesDing it is on organization server where I don't have access :(

Comment: @Ruuteek, Hi Have you tried to disable dynamic compression for IIS server?